# Requests library to send json for API Post

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, post

I'm trying to connect to an API from: https://devzone.revulytics.com/docs/API/authentication.html#authentication-top

I found out about the Requests library and installed it, then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491246/using-python-requests-library-to-send-json-in-http-request) post and a few others and finally compiled this code:

```
import requests

apiURL = "http://api.revulytics.com"
header = {'Host': 'api.revulytics.com', 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'}
json = {"user": "testuser@test.com",
        "password": "mypassword1"}

r = requests.post(apiURL, headers=header, json=json)
print(r.status_code)
```

I messed around with the code a lot and it still doesn't seem to be working - I did change the user and password with my own.

I keep getting 404 when running status_code, which means I failed to connect to the API. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 404 means that there is no endpoint called `/`. According to the page you linked to, the endpoint is `/auth/login`.

So you want

```
apiURL = "https://api.revulytics.com/auth/login"
```

This will make the 404 go away.

Here's my script and the response

```
$ cat p.py
import requests

apiURL = "https://api.revulytics.com/auth/login"
header = {'Host': 'api.revulytics.com', 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'}
json = {"user": "testuser@test.com",
        "password": "mypassword1"}

r = requests.post(apiURL, headers=header, json=json)
print(r.status_code, r.json())

$ python3 p.py
403 {'status': 'AUTH ERROR', 'reason': 'Wrong credentials'}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the 404 error! Now getting a 400 error, but I'm one step closer

`{"errors": ["There was a JSON problem. Correct JSON is required"]}`

Comment: How did you figure out that `auth/login` needed to be pointed at?

Comment: I followed the link you gave, and it said "POST /auth/login". The part after the POST goes in the url. It's actually just a standard way of documenting APIs.